# BIRT - align crosstabs with same dimensions

Tags: birt

Is there any way to align columns of 2 crosstabs to be same size in BIRT?

I have  2 crosstabs in a report, with same dimensions but different values, layout preference set to auto, so the cells are aligned by the cell values.
Is there a way to set second crosstab cells to be aligned as the first one?

Answer (score 0):

That is difficult I guess. One way to solve this is to see if you can combine the two datasets and then group on a parameter that indicates between the two. You could use the pagebreak settings to split the crosstab between the two. With some fancy conditional labels you could make them look quite different. This will make sure the columns align.

Another way could be two use the onCreate script of Crosstab with the function onCreateCell()

```
/**
 * Called when crosstab cell is being created.
 *
 * @param cellInst
 *            ICrosstabCellInstance
 * @param reportContext
 *            IReportContext
 */

function onCreateCell( cellInst, reportContext )
{
}
```

From that cellInst you can get style information like padding, border and color information. I didn't noticed a direct getWidth function, but hey, maybe there is something like it.

perhaps something like:

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement(cellInst.getCellID()).setProperty("width", "10mm");
```

You need to use the reportContext.setGlobalVariable() function to get that information out of the first crosstab context and into the second one. Do a search on crossTab zebra or alternating row colors to find some examples on how to manipulate cells in a crosstab.